# EXCEL/Macro How to find last row

Tags: excel, vba

I used the Recorder to create this small macro... now I just need it to work with variable numbers of row (instead of my row 20000 cheat).

Is there a tip or a trick that can tell this code to stop at the last row?

```
 Columns("K:K").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 Range("K1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
 Range("K2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2]-RC[-3]-RC[-1],""h:mm"")"
 Range("K2").Select
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K20000")
 Range("K2:K20000").Select
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
Sub LastRow()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long


    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you test that? This is riddled with errors, and after they are all fixed, it still returns the last row of any spreadsheet, i.e. 1048576.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to fill down in column K, I assume that this column is empty below the cell K2. Another column probably has data and you want to fill down as far as that other column's last row of data.

To do that, you can determine the last row in that other column, in my example, it's column A, but you can change that. Then plug the variable `lastRow` into your AutoFill statement.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet

lastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

sht.Range("K1").FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
sht.Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2]-RC[-3]-RC[-1],""h:mm"")"
sht.Range("K2").AutoFill Destination:=sht.Range("K2:K" & lastRow)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have your last row in column A:

```
 Columns("K:K").Select
 Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
 Range("K1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total"
 Range("K2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-2]-RC[-3]-RC[-1],""h:mm"")"
 Range("K2").Select
 LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K" & LastRow)
 Range("K2:K" & LastRow).Select
```